# Perl: Alternatives to template toolkit

Tags: perl, templates, template-engine, template-toolkit

I have been using template toolkit for extending an existing domain specific language(verilog) for over 3 years now. While overall I am happy with it, the major irritant is that when there is a syntax/undef error the error message does not contain the correct line number information to debug the error.

e.g. I would get a message indicating "0 is not defined" since I would be using [%x.0%] and similar constructs at multiple locations in the file figuring out which line has the problem becomes difficult.

TT3 seems to be under development indefinitely

My question to the gurus is is there a better alternative to TT. My requirements are

1. Support for complex data structures
2. Good error reporting and debug capabilities.
3. Stable and proven ( no alpha/beta level engines)
4. Extensible (plugin's etc)
5. Should not be restricted to a given language (html etc.)
6. support for IF/Else, looping(foreach while), Loop indexing, etc.
7. Preferably perl
8. Support for data dumper or equivalent plugin from within the template is a plus

Comment: Here is an old writeup.  I don't think it is complete (doesn't include xslate for instance), but may still be helpful to you: https://perl.apache.org/docs/tutorials/tmpl/comparison/comparison.html

Comment: [Xslate](http://xslate.org/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm currently experimenting with [Template::Alloy](https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Alloy) and it seems to be, by and large, a drop-in replacement for TT.  [Template::Alloy::TT](https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Alloy::TT) lists the differences between TT and Alloy, most of which are of the form "This works/is allowed in Alloy, but not in TT."  Addressing your specific issue, the list includes:

> - Alloy has better line information
>
> When debug dirs is on, directives on different lines separated by
>   colons show the line they are on rather than a general line range.
>
> Parse errors actually know what line and character they occured at.

Comment: Tested Template::Alloy today. Debug_dirs is not suitable for my purpose because it assumes that I am generating HTML and inserts HTML style comments.  

For a case of x=[] /*empty array*/ followed by x.0 somewhere in the template Template::Alloy was comparatively more helpful as is gave the complete message x.0 is not defined as opposed to TT2 which said 0 is undefined....  

Will try Xslate tomorrow.

Comment: If I use Template::Alloy and DEBUG => DEBUG_DIRS I get "var.undef error - undefined variable: bar in ln.tt". but it's missing the line information

Comment: As a note for anyone stumbling upon this at a later point in time: T::A is slightly better than TT, but considerably inferior to any other templating library on CPAN. Most damningly, it's been abandoned by its maintainer, with the last release being "SEP 20, 2013", roughly 2 years ago.

Comment: @Mithaldu - Thanks for that update! I'm using Xslate myself these days, too.

Answer (score 20):

I can only recommend [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::Xslate) here. It is better than TT in every way and beats out most of the competition as well. And lastly, it fits all your requirements. Literally. All of them.

It is even proven in practice, as it is used by one of the Top 100 websites worldwide and one of the Top 10 websites in Japan: [Livedoor](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/livedoor.com)

Xslate in comparison to TT:

- faster startup
- faster processing
- strict mode by default
- much more advanced strict mode that catches inconsistencies beyond just "var is undef"
- detailed errors that show the exact template position
- automatic HTML entity escaping (XSS-safe)
- [actively maintained](https://github.com/xslate/p5-Text-Xslate/issues) and not just [left to languish](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Template-Toolkit)
- syntax is straight-forward and modern perl

---

Two things to note for your special case:

1. As you're porting from TT, you might want to pass `syntax => 'TTerse'` to the constructor to get a syntax that's designed to be as close to TT as possible.
2. When generating non-HTML, you want to pass `type => 'text'` to the constructor to disable `html_escape` interpolation.

Comment: I agree that xslate meets most of my specification. But since Template Alloy addressed my major problem (cryptic error messages) and has syntax similar to TT (less migration headache) I am going with it for my project

Comment: You did see the note i wrote about enabling TT syntax in Xslate? There is not a single thing T::A is superior to Xslate in, and a number of things where it's actively inferior. You opted for the worse choice here, for what can only be described as "no reason whatsoever".

Comment: I agree that you may be right. I will do an eval of Xslate on of these days. If as you say XSlate supports the complete TT Syntax the transition should be seamless. I will comeback and comment on this thread once I am done with the eval

Comment: I did not expect an answer to this, so i have to say: Thank you. :) As a note, the TT syntax is not *completely* supported, but enough of it is supported that transitions should be quite trivial. :)

Comment: I benchmarked Xslate against Template and mojo::template and I found that  Xslate is no longer that fasted. It is about 5 times faster than Template, and 2x slower than mojo::template.

Comment: Link to benchmark, and feature comparison of the two?

Answer (score 10):

[Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) comes with its own templating system [Mojo::Template](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Template). Its lightweight and can be used even outside of the mojolicious system. Here is an example from the docs:

```
use Mojo::Template;
  my $mt = Mojo::Template->new;

  # Simple
  my $output = $mt->render(<<'EOF');
  % use Time::Piece;
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head><title>Simple</title></head>
    % my $now = localtime;
    <body>Time: <%= $now->hms %></body>
  </html>
  EOF
  say $output;
```

and another

```
  # More advanced
  my $output = $mt->render(<<'EOF', 23, 'foo bar');
  % my ($number, $text) = @_;
  %= 5 * 5
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head><title>More advanced</title></head>
    <body>
      test 123
      foo <% my $i = $number + 2; %>
      % for (1 .. 23) {
      * some text <%= $i++ %>
      % }
    </body>
  </html>
  EOF
  say $output;
```

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment? Mojo::Template addresses all the OPs concerns and is quick and easy to install and start using.

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest HTML::Template:Compiled (but note I'm the author ;-)

It is quite compatible to HTML::Template, but has additional features.

> Support for complex data structures

yes

> Good error reporting and debug capabilities.

You can debug cache hits, misses, automatically add template filename to output and can use a filter "DUMP" for the current variable in stash (or any variable).
If it's easy to implement I'll happily add more useful debugging.

> Stable and proven ( no alpha/beta level engines)

I would consider it stable now, with the documented limitations/bugs (for example query())

> Extensible (plugin's etc)

supports escape (filter) plugins and more, though the latter is not documented very well yet.

> Should not be restricted to a given language (html etc.)

yes

> support for IF/Else, looping(foreach while), Loop indexing, etc.

yes

> Preferably perl

yes

> Support for data dumper or equivalent plugin from within the template is a plus

like mentioned above, use escape=dump

all additional features are listed in the documentation:
https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-Template-Compiled
at "ADDITIONAL FEATURES"

edit: regarding reporting runtime errors: unfortunately H::T::C also does not report the template line number for errors that happen at runtime, since it compiles the template to perl-code (I think I experimented with manipulating line numbers once, maybe I'll have another look).
template syntax errors are reported with the correct line number.

edit2:
So here's an example with the new options warnings and line_info:

t/templates/line_info1.html:

```
test
test2
test3
foo:<%= foo %> undef line 4
test4
```

script:

```
use HTML::Template::Compiled;
my $t = HTML::Template::Compiled->new(
    filename => "t/templates/line_info1.html",
    warnings => 1,
    line_info => 1,
);
say $t->output;
__END__
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at t/templates/line_info1.html line 4.
test
test2
test3
foo: undef line 4
test4
```

Comment: tinita, regretfully I am looking to move away from TT only because it does not report the correct line numbers for the error :(

Comment: @vijayvithal: I had another look and it seems to be possible by adding a SIG handler for __WARN__ and by manipulating line numbers via #line directives. test suite suceeds.

Comment: oh, I don't need the sig handler at all. I think about adding an option to activate this feature in the next version.

Comment: @vijayvithal: I uploaded 1.000_004. added option 'warnings' and 'line_info' (forgot to update Changes file though)

Answer (score 2):

take a look on [Template::Semantic](http://search.cpan.org/~tomita/Template-Semantic/) for pure template abstraction